# Symfony 4 Twig Custom Form Field Template For Collection Of Checkboxes

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I've used a custom template no problem when using a collection of checkboxes to change the html to be in a table like this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _packing_dispatch_form_group_formsA_0_packagingList_widget %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table>
                {%- for child in form %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="firstCol">{{- form_label(child, null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}</td>
                        <td>{{- form_widget(child) -}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor -%}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But now the collection has changed so it holds a collection of another form type which then holds the checkboxes, i can't figure out how i now apply the same template to the new collection of the second form type.

Here is the code:

PackagingDispatchFormGroupType.php

```
$data= [];
            $packingForm = new PackingDispatchForm();
            $data[] = $packingForm;

            $builder->add('formsA', CollectionType::class,[
               'entry_type'=>PackingDispatchFormType::class,
                'entry_options'=>[
                    'user'=>$this->user
                ],
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'data'=>$data,
                'mapped'=>false
            ]);
```

PackagingDispatchFormType.php

```
->add('packagingList',ChoiceType::class,[
                'multiple'=>true,
                'expanded'=>true,
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'packagingListInput'
                ],
                'choices'=>[
                    'Digitherm Camera, CDX8950-400' => 'Digitherm Camera, CDX8950-400',
                    'Battery, CDX370PACK' => 'Battery, CDX370PACK',
                    'Battery Tab, CDX8950-514' => 'Battery Tab, CDX8950-514',
                    'Memory Card, CDX8IS' => 'Memory Card, CDX8IS',
                    'Memory Card Reader, CDXUSBR' => 'Memory Card Reader, CDXUSBR',
                    'Charging Station, CDX370D' => 'Charging Station, CDX370D',
                    'Power Supply (3x Adapters), CDX370C' => 'Power Supply (3x Adapters), CDX370C',
                    'Australian Adapter' => 'Australian Adapter',
                    'Access Key, XP-100' => 'Access Key, XP-100',
                    'Wrist Strap, CDX8950-550' => 'Wrist Strap, CDX8950-550',
                    'Fragrance Card, CDX8950-512' => 'Fragrance Card, CDX8950-512',
                    'Accessory Card' => 'Accessory Card',
                    'Instructions For Safe User, CDX8950-511 Rev. A' => 'Instructions For Safe User, CDX8950-511 Rev. A',
                    'User Manual, CDX8950-507, Rev. A' => 'User Manual, CDX8950-507, Rev. A',
                    'Battery Warning Card' => 'Battery Warning Card',
                    'Charger Instruction Leaflet' => 'Charger Instruction Leaflet',
                    'Declaration Of Conformity, SOM15, Rev. A' => 'Declaration Of Conformity, SOM15, Rev. A'
                ],
                'disabled'=>($this->forView ? true : false),
                'choice_attr'=>function($choice, $key, $value){
                    return ['required'=>true];
                },
                'invalid_message'=>'All Of The Packaging List Checkboxes Are Required'
            ]);
```

The whole point here is that i can now duplicate the form field as an array of the checkboxes, but can't seem to apply the same html template.

Comment: I always use {{ dump(form.yourfieldname.vars.block_prefixes) }} to find out the correct block to overwrite.

Comment: @Vyctorya interesting idea, i'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Vyctorya yeh i'm having a bit of an issue with doign this because of the array collection, if i try {{ dump(form.packing_dispatch_form_group_formsA_packagingList.vars) }} it gives an error, if i try {{ dump(form.packing_dispatch_form_group_formsA_0_packagingList.vars) }} it also gives an error of not found

Comment: Do {{ dump(form.Forms) }} and then search for all appearances of 'block_prefixes'. The blockname will be something close to '_packing_dispatch_form_group_formsA_entry_packagingList_widget'.

Comment: @Vyctorya this just gives an internal server error

Comment: @Vyctorya sorted it a different way, so the only key i can see is "_packing_dispatch_form_group_formsA" in the "block_prefixes" which doesn't work in the template

Comment: Actually it's ok, your example was correct! Please can you reply as an answer so i can mark it as done?